# Javascript protobuf performance

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, protobufjs

Two different modules are available for protobuf in nodejs -

1. https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/
2. https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/js - official but less features than the other module. Specifically, doesn't have typescript integration.

Which one has better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the protobuf.js [performance](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/#performance) section, protobuf.js is significantly more performant than the official implementation.